# Get SMS log and insert into database Twilio account

Tags: php, twilio

I am trying to store incoming sms log in Twilio.
I have also checked APIs given `https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183588-Exporting-SMS-and-Call-Logs` in this page but it is downloading csv file and also data is encrypted(non readable).

This is response in csv file "畯摮愭楰⴬⸰㄰唬䑓㜊", in both case using API and using admin dashboard.

I am not understanding the reason.

Please suggest.
[image]

Comment: Are you using the correct encoding when downloading the file ?   For example UTF-8   ?

Comment: Please check attched screen as it's on click export to csv. and in API there is no params for encoding.

Comment: I added a screenshot to Sachin's solution with my findings -  your viewer is not reading the file properly.  When you said as received over API, again, this would be an encoding issue.  Correct the encoding and/or swap to a viewer that views it properly.  I suggest Notepad++ for your testing, or if on linux - open in vim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked this api with my twilio account.

This is not the problem of api that is given by twilio, you need to check the encoding of excel or libra office(in case you are using ubuntu).

---

Here is a screenshot of contents of the file I received when clicking the [Export to CSV] button viewed in Notepad++ :

[image]

Comment: Ok let me check with this once.

Comment: @jyoti mishra if this is the answer of your question, then accept it!

Answer (score 0):

This was problem of encoding in my Libra office only, It is working fine after changing that. Thanks all for your help.